# How report Standar error of measurement (SEM)?

Tags: error

How report standard error of measurement (SEM)? Always with "±" due is a range?

Answer (score 3):

The standard error of the mean, SEM, should be reported in a manner that makes it clear to the reader. Given that the ± thing can be applied to SEM, SD, interval bounds, and maybe other things, it is not sufficient to just report ±SEM. You do not need to always use the ± symbol. Different disciplines and different journals have different preferred styles, so you could check the style guide of a relevant journal. If in doubt, you should specify explicitly what the variability number represents.

SEM is not the "standard error of measurement". The 'mean' in its name is important because the SEM is an estimation from the data of the standard deviation of (theoretical) means from the sample size used repeatedly drawn from the same population as the original sample.

Comment: https://www.statisticshowto.com/standard-error-of-measurement/

Comment: https://us.humankinetics.com/blogs/excerpt/standard-error-of-measurement

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327273189_Standard_Error_of_Measurement

Comment: In response to your links (only one that I clicked: if you can't b e botherred writing words then I don't see why a reader would be bothered reading them!) I will say that even if 'standard error of measurement' is a thing, the advice on how to present it is the same.

Comment: Of course that standar error of the measurement it´s a thing...there is lot of papers about it. Links are information about.